# How to check index of a DataFrame for first day of the month

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

If I have a DataFrame indexed by datetimes, how can I select the rows corresponding to the first day of each month, or check if a given row is at the first day of a month?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the User guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html) practicing the examples. .

Answer (score 4):

Select all rows with first day by compare [`DatetimeIndex.day`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.day.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df[df.index.day == 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way, use the [`is_month_start`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.is_month_start.html#pandas.DatetimeIndex.is_month_start) attribute with boolean indexing:

```
df[df.index.is_month_start]
```

Technically, this should be the fastest way, since this is already an attribute of the DateTimeIndex.